# Crop images in single line

Tags: command-line

With the following bash command that crops an image, I would like to loop through from `02` to `18`, using a single line command.

```
convert TOS28_Page_02.jpg -crop 990x1500+0+0 TOS28_Page_02a.x.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for((i=2;i<19;++i));do printf "convert TOS28_Page_%02d.jpg -crop 990x1500+0+0 TOS28_Page_%02da.x.jpg;" $i $i;done|sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `xargs` and `bash` or `zsh` (no loop):

```
printf '%s\n' {02..18} |
    xargs -I {} echo convert "TOS28_Page_{}.jpg" \
       -crop "990x1500+0+0 TOS28_Page_{}a.x.jpg"
```

One line version:

```
printf '%s\n' {02..18} | xargs -I {} echo convert "TOS28_Page_{}.jpg" -crop "990x1500+0+0 TOS28_Page_{}a.x.jpg"
```

Remove `echo` command when the output looks satisfactory.

Comment: Alternatively, `seq` can be used to generate the file names with `seq -f "TOS28_Page_%02g.jpg" 2 18` which can then be piped into xargs.

Comment: `seq` is a binary while I use only _buit-ins_ functions

Comment: That's true. I didn't realize it in the moment but omitting `seq -f` and replacing it with `printf` would yield the same result, so looks like seq doesn't have anything special to offer which printf doesn't in this instance. Cheers

Comment: seq(1) is nonstandard, inefficient and useless.